# How to I make the actor jump without stopping the entire code?

Tags: python, pygame, pgzero

I am attempting to make the `dino` jump, but when I use `time.sleep(0.1)` in between the `dino` jumping and falling, the whole game stops for 0.1 seconds.

I have tried using time.sleep and that's it as I can't find any other useful info online.

```py
def jump():
    dino.y -= 100
    time.sleep(0.1)
    dino.y += 100

def on_key_up(key):
    jump()
```

When I press the up arrow, the entire game freezes for 0.1 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use a timer event. When the player jumps, then start a timer by [`pygame.time.set_timer()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer). When the timer event occurs, then finish the jump:

```py
jump_delay = 100 # 100 milliseconds == 0.1 seconds
jump_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
```

```py
def jump():
    dino.y -= 100

    # start a timer event which just appear once in 0.1 seconds
    pygame.time.set_timer(jump_event, jump_delay, True)

def on_key_up(key):
    jump()
```

```
# event loop
for event in pygame.event.get():

    # jump timer event
    if event.type == jump_event:
       dino.y += 100

# [...]
```

Note, in pygame customer events can be defined. Each event needs a unique id. The ids for the user events have to start at `pygame.USEREVENT`. In this case `pygame.USEREVENT+1` is the event id for the timer event, which finishes the jump.

---

[Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news) is not [Pygame Zero](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Anyway, if you use [Pygame Zero](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), then you can use the elapsed time parameter of the [`update`](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/hooks.html#update) callback:

> ```py
> def uptate(dt):
> ```

The elapsed time parameter (`dt`) give the time which is passed since the lat frame in seconds.

Create a state (`jump`) which indicates if the `dino` is jumping. And a time (`jump_time`), which states how long the jump has to be continued:

```py
jump = False
jump_time = 0.0
```

Set the state and the time in `jump`:

```py
def jump():
    global jump, jump_time
    dino.y -= 100
    jump = True
    jump_time = 0.1 # 0.1 seconds
```

Decrement the time in `update` and finish the jump respectively rest the `jump` state, if the `jump_time` is less than 0.0:

```py
def uptate(dt):

    if jump:
        jump_time -= dt
        if jump_time < 0:
            dino.y += 100
            jump = False
```

Comment: This has fixed the problem of the entire game freezing but the Dino does not jump and it is now impossible to close the game window. To close the game I have to close shell instead. Any suggestions?

Comment: It won't accept a while loop as the main loop because other things in the main loop rely on the `def update():` which is part of the pygame library. Therefore I get the same result as I cannot add `run = True`.

Comment: @TimeLord272 *"the main loop rely on the `def update():` which is part of the pygame library"* No, you're wrong. There is no `update` call back in pygame. Do you use something like [Pygame Zero](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)?

Comment: @TimeLord272 [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news) is not [Pygame Zero](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), but if you use `pgzrun`, then see the 2nd section of the answer.